# Using an array to calculate and store the percentage increase from one year to the next

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

I'm working on a program for my programming class in college. I got most of it to work properly,but the end loop i'm trying to use doesn't work right. I'm not quite sure whats going on. I like to learn more and figure out why it's doing this. My problem is at the end where I show the increase between years in a percentage. I'm trying to take the (year+1)-year/(year+1). Now I have my variables as integers and I want to cast my denominator to a float point. My answers kept coming up with 100.00%, -1.#J%, and 98.24% when I run the program. Below is a copy of what I got so far. An help will be gladly appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define years 4
#define months 12
int main(void)
{
    float percentage [4];
    float answer = 0.0;
    int i = 0, j = 0, n = 0, sum = 0;
    int time[] = {2012,2013,2014,2015};
    int value[years];
    const char* name[]= {"    JAN "," FEB ", " MAR ", " APR ", " MAY ", " JUN ", " JUL  ","AUG "," SEP "," OCT "," NOV "," DEC "};
    int range[years][months] = {

        { 5626, 5629, 5626, 5606, 5622, 5633, 5647, 5656, 5673, 5682, 5728, 5728},
        { 5741, 5793, 5814, 5811, 5831, 5854, 5857, 5874, 5900, 5923, 5954, 5939},
        { 5999, 6020, 6062, 6103, 6115, 6128, 6169, 6194, 6219, 6233, 6256, 6301},
        { 6351, 6378, 6371, 6409, 6426, 6426, 6437, 6441, 6451, 6484, 6549, 6597}
    };

    printf("YEAR");
    for(n=0; n < months; n++)
        printf("%s", name[n]);

    for (i = 0; i < years; i++) {
        printf(" \n%i    ", time[i]);
        for (j = 0; j < months; j++)
            printf("%2i ", range[i][j]);
            printf("\n");
    }

    for (i = 0; i < years; i++) {
        for(j = 0, sum = 0; j < months; j++)
            sum += range[i][j];
            printf("\n This is the sum of months for %i: %i", time[i], sum);


    }
    printf("\n\n");
    for (i = 0; i < years-1; i++)
    {
        value[i] = 0;
        for(j = 0, sum = 0; j < months; j++)
            {
                value[i] += range[i][j];
                percentage[i]= (value[i+1]-value[i])/(float)value[i+1];
            }

    printf("\n The increase from %i to %i was: %.2f%% ", time[i], time[i+1], percentage[i]*100);
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: It is good you want to learn. So now it is time to learn how to use the debugger. Step through the code and check the variables if they have the expected values.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will take a look at the debugger. They haven't really showed me in school how to use it , but i will start looking at it and figuring it out. I use the build log to determine some of my errors so far.

Comment: On the debugger, do I type in a line of the code to scan it?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to use the debugger. Build log shows zero errors and zero warnings.

Comment: Typically no. I have no idea which debugger you use. The user interfaces can differ quite a lot. But that is part of learning, isn't it?

Comment: I'm using CodeBlocks

Comment: Do you see anything wrong with my code that I'm trying to make the calculations with at the bottom?

Comment: Code::Blocks is an IDE. Please understand this is not tutoring site. I think you wanted to learn? That includes you find out on your own.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the flagship site of the Stack Exchange Network, created in 2008 by Jeff Atwood and Joel Spolsky. It was created to be a more open alternative to earlier Q&A sites such as Experts-Exchange.

Comment: I have questions, so far your answers are not helpful at all.

Comment: You seem to have forgot to read [ask]. Rules are set by the community. I tried to help you. If you prefer complaining instead of showing some research on your own, fee free. But keep in mind, no one likes whining kids.

Comment: Oh, and comments are not to answer. Read about that, too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last for loop, you can't say `percentage[i]= (value[i+1] -value[i])/(float)value[i+1];` because you haven't initialized `value[i+1]` yet. Only thing you can do is to use backward indexing like `((float)value[i] - (float)value[i-1])/(float)value[i];`
In the case of the first calculation, it won't work but in the first calculation, you have 0% increase because it is the first year and you have nothing to compare with.

---

Actually, try this. I think this will match your goal:

```
printf("\n\n");
for (i = 0; i < years; i++) {
    value[i] = 0;
    for(j = 0, sum = 0; j < months; j++) value[i] += range[i][j];
}
for(i = 0; i < years-1; i++) {
    percentage[i]= (value[i+1]-value[i])/(float)value[i+1];
    printf("\n The increase from %i to %i was: %.2f%% ", time[i], time[i+1], percentage[i]*100);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I kind of see what i did wrong and how your code is working. I was close just had some of my logic backwards and I was missing another for loop. I really appreciate it.